# How to -remove multiple items at once?

Tags: powershell, formatting

I currently have a list of 25,000+ server names. Each name has a ton of extra stuff added on to the name, which I want to remove. Here is a sample data:

```
WindowsAuthServer @{htew804WIN}
```

I want to remove "WindowsAutherServer @{" and "WIN}" from each server, leaving just "htew804" left. I currently have:

```
$remove1 = $file -remove "WindowsAutherServer @{",""
$final = $remove1 -remove "WIN}",""
```

This works, but I would like to do it all in one step if possible. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

This `RegEx` could do it in one go:

```
$str = "WindowsAuthServer @{htew804WIN}"
$str -replace '.*?{(.*?)WIN}','$1'
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Escaping the literal curly braces wasn't neccessary here, but would escaping them from being a quantifier slow down or speed up processing?

Comment: @LotPings I'm not that versed in regular expressions, but since they should be parsed as literal characters here I wouldn't expect an adverse effect on performance. The leading `.*?` probably has a more significant effect.

Comment: @TobyU There was nothing wrong with the `$` anchor. In fact, anchoring expressions is good practice. However, `^.*` (or `.*$` for that matter) aren't actually anchoring anything due to the `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you want to keep instead.

```
"WindowsAuthServer @{htew804WIN}" | foreach { $x = $_ -match '\@\{(.+)WIN}' ; $Matches[1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using [`String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) and [`String.LastIndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof) methods:

```
$str = "WindowsAuthServer @{htew804WIN}"
$str.Substring(($open = $str.LastIndexOf('{') + 1), $str.LastIndexOf('}') - $open - 3)
```

We first use `String.LastIndexOf('{')` to find the last occurrence of `{`, then (using that as an offset) calculate the length until just before `WIN}`

Answer (score 0):

Or this one:

```
$str = "WindowsAuthServer @{htew804WIN}"
([regex]'@\{(\w+)WIN\}').Match($str).Groups[1].Value;
```