# Modifying Column Within Array

Tags: powershell, csv, formatting, psobject

I'm reading in a CSV file which contains 25,000 records, and am reading each column into a `psobject`. Here is what I have so far:

```
$file = Import-CSV .\server.csv
$tempobj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    'Name' = $file.Name
    'Group' = $file.Group
}
```

When this is ran, I get the correct results I want, being that `$file.Name` contains all the server names, and `$file.Group` contains the groups for servers. However, my issue is that I need to edit the names of each server without interfering with the `.Group`. Here is an example of what a server name look like as is.

```
WindowsAuthServer @{wdk9870WIN}
```

I need to remove `WindowsAuthServer @{` and `WIN}` from each server name, leaving only the server name left, or for this example, `wdk9870`.

I tried using the `-replace` function (`$tempobj.Name -replace "WindowsAuthServer @{",""`), but it requires that I save the results to a new array, which then messes up or removes `.Group` entirely

Is there a different way to go about doing this? I'm lost.

Comment: Each column is *already* a `pscustomobject` because you're using `Import-Csv`.  You're doubly-processing each record.  Also, you're looking at the string-representation of a `pscustomobject`; the string is not literally `WindowsAuthServer @{wdk9870WIN}`.  The key `WindowsAuthServer` contains the value `wdk9870WIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your `server.csv` looks like this:

```
"Name","Group"
"WindowsAuthServer @{wdk9870WIN}","Group1"
"WindowsAuthServer @{wdk9880WIN}","Group2"
"WindowsAuthServer @{wdk9890WIN}","Group1"
"WindowsAuthServer @{wdk9900WIN}","Group1"
```

And you want to change the values in the `Name` column only, then something like this would probably do it:

```
Import-Csv .\server.csv | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        'Name' = ([regex]'@\{(\w+)WIN\}').Match($_.Name).Groups[1].Value
        'Group' = $_.Group
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
Name    Group 
----    ----- 
wdk9870 Group1
wdk9880 Group2
wdk9890 Group1
wdk9900 Group1
```

If you want, you can simply pipe this info to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet to save as a new CSV file. For that, just append `| Export-Csv -Path .\server_updated.csv -NoTypeInformation` to the code.

Hope that helps

Comment: It's highly unlikely their data actually looks like that.  It's more likely they're looking at the console and don't understand that everything in powershell is an object, so it's a string-representation of a `pscustomobject` for console-printing.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes, that could very well be the case, although if I look at the OP's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53834831/9898643) I can't be sure..

Comment: Oof. I sincerely hope they're not doing something like `| Out-String | Out-File` to a csv somehow.